# Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit) Caching 302 Redirect Incorrectly?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, http-status-code-302, no-cache

After updating to Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit), I'm seeing some strange behavior in one of my 302 redirects (shown below).

The cache-control headers are set to `no-cache, must-revalidate`, yet Chrome now randomly serves content from the disk cache.

Is this a new Chrome bug, or expected behavior?

[image]

Note - The request has been had some parts cut out because this is not a publicly accessible system.  The URL, Remote IP, and CloudFlare Ray wouldn't provide any useful details unless you're on the white-list.

*EDIT*
A test URL can be found here:

https://v2.thinklikeamage.com/test302.php

This page will issue a 302 redirect with a no-cache, must-revalidate Cache-Control header.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that now Google Chrome can store the result of 302 redirects within local disk cache if `no-store` is not specified.

Adding `no-store` to the Cache-Control header seems to prevent local disk caching.

-- alternatively --

The 'Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly' setting seems to be tied to this now as well.  Switching off this feature seems to alleviate the original issue, but does little to help end-users that may be affected by it.